# O que é o Riot.js?

Tags: javascript, html5, front-end, web-component

Estava lendo sobre alguns frameworks e bibliotecas para desenvolvimento de UI front-end e me deparei com o [Riot.js](http://riotjs.com).

Dando uma rápida lida na [página](http://riotjs.com) da biblioteca (em inglês), concluí superficialmente que eles prometem facilitar a componentização da UI por meio da sua biblioteca.

Surgiram então as dúvidas:

- Como já existem várias bibliotecas/frameworks com propósito parecido (Angular, React, Vue, etc.) quais seriam as motivações para se escolher Riot.js?
- As "custom tags" que eles oferecem não quebram padrões da web?
- Qual seria então, uma visão geral sobre a biblioteca?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claramente exposta na documentação, [Riot](http://riotjs.com/compare/) foi inspirado no React do Facebook. A proposta deles é possuir sintaxe simples, e ser leve - leveza é um ponto audacioso a se tocar, porque se a leveza em questão é no desempenho da biblioteca é um desafio para eles competirem com React, principalmente devido a melhor sacada, pra mim, do Facebook - o Virtual DOM.

Riot possui Express Binding, que basicamente armazena as expressões criadas em um array, e cada expressão tem um ponteiro para o nó no DOM. Obviamente que discutir sobre a estrutura de atualização de elementos na árvore DOM é um assunto pra outro almoço (ou post), porém é importante se atentar a isso, porque o que mais difere o concorrente direto do Riot é a estrutura de componentização e Virtual DOM.

E Riot é basicamente isso, um biblioteca com sintaxe mais simples do que seus similares, que tem uma atenção especial no trabalho com templates e que tentou/tenta resolver furos do React.

Comment: Você teria um exemplo do que seria um "furo" no React que o Riot resolva?

Comment: Sintaxe complexa e não legível para humanos. Precisar de muito para criar, por exemplo um SPA. Riot promete entregar o "mesmo" resultado por menos, sabendo que está usando somente o necessário.

Answer (score 1):

> Como já existem várias bibliotecas/frameworks com propósito parecido
>   (Angular, React, Vue, etc.) quais seriam as motivações para se
>   escolher Riot.js?

Isso depende do projeto, Riot.Js é muito leve e facilita bastante na criacao de template, agora se voce precisa de algo que precise tabalhar lado a lado com o back-end react nao seria uma boa solucao em comparaçao com as outras frameworks

> As "custom tags" que eles oferecem não quebram padrões da web?

Edit:
Gerar novas tags deixa o html depedente da framework, impossibilitado a troca de framework, nao existe uma quebra de padrão e sim um novo padrão implementado.

> Qual seria então, uma visão geral sobre a biblioteca?

Gerar template com mais facilidade.

e tem uma boa comparacao bem resumida sobre algumas frameworks aqui: https://nurelm.com/front-end-soup-react-polymer-riot-ember-angular-aurelia/ material em ingles

Comment: Se as *custom tags* não quebram os padrões da Web, de que forma elas atrapalhariam o desenvolvimento, já que elas fazem parte do padrão e todo desenvolvedor terá conhecimento sobre?

Comment: Também tive esta dúvida, como elas se encaixam nos padrões da W3C?

Comment: @BrenoCosta https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/

Comment: Interessante! Obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: "Padrão web" nao estar relacionado com naming, no momento que vc cria uma nova coleção de nomes automaticamente vc esta fazendo um novo padrão. O negativo disso é a depedencia na framework impossibilitando a sua troca.

Comment: eu editei minha resposta sobre o padrao